# Something wrong with the class file

Tags: c#, wpf

I using C# and WPF to build my app. So heres the problem....i got my mainWindow.xaml file with its mainWindow.cs file. I also create another class file Setting.cs. I try to take the check box from the mainWindow.xaml to the setting.cs and process it and then send back to the mainWindow.cs. But when i open it, it couldn't be close and the process i add in the setting.cs doesn't work. Is it something to do with the "public static void" ?

Here's my Setting.cs:

```
public class Setting
{

public static void loadSetting()
    {
       MainWindow win = new MainWindow();
       XDocument document = XDocument.Load("UserSetting.xml");

        var query = from p in document.Descendants("user_Setting")
                    where p.Element("id").Value == "1"
                    select p;

        XElement element = query.First();
        element.SetElementValue("Keep_Login",saveCheckBox(win.MyCheckBox);
    }

public static void saveCheckBox(System.windows.Controls.CheckBox checkBox)
   {
        string status = "";
        if (checkBox.IsChecked == true)
            status = "true";
        else if (checkBox.IsChecked == false)
            status = "false";

        return status;
    }
}
```

My MainWindow.cs:

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Setting.loadSetting(); 
    }
```

Comment: I think you might want to pass your MainWindow class into the loadSetting method: Setting.loadSetting(this); That way you do not have to create a new instance of MainWindow in the loadSetting method.

Comment: Did you check your target framework? I often got the same problem when the target framework is set to ".NET 4 Client Profile" instead of ".NET 4".

Comment: @stuartmclark:Haha solved! Yes, need to put Setting.loadSetting(this) in the main.cs and in the setting.cs put in the public static void loadSetting(MainWindow main). Thanks for your  advice =D

Comment: @0070 Not a problem buddy, glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not compile:

```
public static **string** saveCheckBox(System.windows.Controls.CheckBox checkBox)
{
    string status = "";
    if (checkBox.IsChecked == true)
        status = "true";
    else if (checkBox.IsChecked == false)
        status = "false";

    return status;
}
```

This way you can do something with the result of you code. I whould recommend to use a bool as result instead of a string and change the name of the method, because you are not saving anything.

Comment: +1 It doesn't compile... and good advice.. by the looks of the method you should be using a bool as a return type.

Comment: @peer : Acutally it work just fine if i dint seperate the code into another class file....but when i do, problem come out.

Comment: @0070 it can't work fine if it does not compile, if you are running code. It is not the code in your editor.